# Unconsistent data retrieveing from database

Tags: php, url-rewriting

Recently a problem occured in functionallity of my website and I cant get any idea why this is happening.
The problem is that i can't get almost any data from database. In some cases there is possible to retrieve text for an article but in most cases it is not happening.
Here is example. 
If i open page via this link http://www.positive.rs/racunari?id_tip_komp=55&artikal=20068 it will open that page. 
But if I choose any other link it will open home page of webshop.

And on some other section of site i can open links only if URLs arent rewriten (http://positive.rs/medija-centar?page=novosti&more=windows-8-pro-upgrade-za-8-hiljada-dinara) but using rewriten URL i cant get it to work. 
I've cleared .htaccess but those attempts were unsuccesseful.

Any idea how to solve this problem?